# Param 'link' should not be on FDL domain for Firebase Dynamic Link (FDL)

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

This is the error I am getting on Firebase Dynamic Link:

Param 'link' should not be on FDL domain.  I understand that it shouldn't be on the same domain...but when I [read the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/flutter/create), I don't see any coloring and it looks like the domains are the same.

This is the link generating the error:

```
https://thecentral.page.link?link=https://thecentral.page.link/initQRProfile/19XsZFmih0UXy5g83YeM4HCciIN2-byj999BOfwcXSXpHtX1R&ibi=pckg.thecentral&isi=6444295624&st=Counterparty: 100 Private Clubs in Your Pocket&d=1
```